# Can a (Hausdorff) infinite group have only finitely many equivalence classes of irreducible unitary representations?

Tags: representation-theory

(Where two representations are equivalent iff they are unitarily equivalent.)

Comment: I suggest going through classes of groups and checking whether you get any examples. Compact groups -- no; locally compact abelian - no, reductive Lie groups - no ( harder to justify); infinite Coxeter groups - no ( $\mathbb{Z}$ is a quotient). Great question.

Comment: Do you mean to include topological groups? If so do you want some hypotheses on the topology? (Hausdorff is clearly necessary or else there are dumb counterexamples involving groups with the indiscrete topology.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I would like to impose the Hausdorff condition, yes. I will edit. Otherwise I wanted it to be somewhat open-ended. I guess I am mostly interested in the locally compact case.

Comment: The Gelfand Raikov theorem states that for a LCH group, the irreducible representations separate points. Somehow,I would expect this to imply that there are I infinitely many nonequivalent ones,but atm I don't see it.